# Execute JavaScript from ASP.NET Server on Page Load

Tags: javascript, asp.net, vb.net

I need to call the following code to render a combox box using JQuery's UI library:

```js
//renders combobox element with JQueryUI library
function renderComboBox() {
    $("#combobox").combobox();
}
```

I can execute it just fine when I include the following js in the header:

```js
//when doc is ready calls into function to render combobox
$(function() {
    renderComboBox();
});
```

However, based on conditions available at load time, I either need to decide to run or not run the code.  I'd like to do that with something similar to the following:

```vb
Private Sub Page1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    If .... Then
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, _ 
            "RenderCombo", "renderComboBox();", True)
    End If
End Sub
```

But it doesn't seem to be working.  Any thoughts?

*Update*: [Here's](http://jsfiddle.net/KyleMit/DaBke/4/) a jsFiddle to demonstrate what I'm trying to do, but it's not super helpful because it doesn't help run through any of the ASP.NET specific code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because it's all relying on JQuery, you need to make sure your `renderComboBox()` only fires when the page is ready, So add `$(function() { })` code to the code your outputting on your `page_load`

What is currently happening is your page loads, and the `renderComboBox()` fires right away - and it will be firing before any of your JQuery or UI is ready.

So try modifying your Javascript to this:

```
   ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType, _ 
        "RenderCombo", "$(function() { renderComboBox();})", True)
```